# how to handle series data when you can't predict data set?

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I'd like to create a highchart line chart with drill down to addition data.

The first data point would be date and total count, i.e., (2019-04-01, 3,000)- I have that part down and displaying.

The drilldown would be a break down of the total, such as:

Cats 1,000

Dogs 1,000

Pigs 1,000

I can do that too, but only when I can predict the drilldown series. The data set is dynamic, it could, for example, sometimes include birds and fish, or not have pigs.

I've create a pie chart with drilldown and set an array to have the drilldown data... I could pull this off because the data was predictable. I'm using PHP to create the data set but could use python or csv is that makes it feasible.

The drilldown should be dynamic and be able to handle any introduced series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @ShujolNYC, Please describe your problem more precisely. Also, some code that you have tried would be very useful.